# Limpar document write

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando coletar a hora através de um servidor onde rodo a seguinte app,
so que o problema é que quando eu do o res.write ele se repete, existe alguma maneira de limpar a tela para gerar um novo write?

```
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res, err) {

    if(err){ throw err; }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var time = new Date();
    setInterval(function(){

        time = new Date();
        res.write(
            time.getHours()
            + ':' +
            time.getMinutes()
            + ':' +
            time.getSeconds() 
        );

       // res.end();

    },1000);
}).listen(8090);
```

Comment: Ele se repete na mesma requisição? Não entendi bem desculpe, poderia explicar em que momento se repete?

Comment: quando eu busco localhost:8090 ele aparece assm.. 10:00:0110:00:02 10:00:03 ... e se repete, eu queria que ficasse estático

Comment: Não é por causa do `setInterval`?

Comment: sim mais eu preciso atualizar para jogar em um iframe

Comment: Mas a atualização não deveria ser feita pelo front-end a cada requisição? Até mesmo usar Ajax de preferencia

Comment: já tentou `res.send`?

Comment: nao pq eu quero a hora do servidor , esse ap irá servir varias páginas

Comment: @RafaelVergoPolan Vou concordar com o Guilherme, se vc tem um setInval e o processo é assíncrono e ele vai ficar escrevendo várias vezes na response até enviar a resposta. Porque está usando setInterval?

Comment: estou tentando gerar pela maneira mais simples sem express, o interval é para atualizar a hora em tempo real

Comment: Talvez você deve-se usar algo como `http.request(options, callback);`, desculpe se estou falando bobagem, nunca usei Node.js.

Comment: vou tem que fazer pelo client.. diretamente pelo server creio que não da

Comment: É mais ou menos isso que eu queria dizer. Uma pergunta, por que `<iframe>` não seria melhor ajax?

Comment: pq vou ter que ficar fazendo requisições para atualizar a hora

Comment: @RafaelVergoPolan, você pode usar websockets, daí vai receber atualizações em tempo real, mas só para atualizar a hora acho que é o famoso caso da "bazuca mata moscas"

Comment: Rafael mas é exatamente isto que o ajax faz, requisições ao servidor :)

Answer (score 1):

Isso que você quer fazer especificamente não é possível. No entanto, existem formas simples de se resolver isso, mesmo usando apenas HTTP, ao invés de algo como WebSockets ou uma biblioteca como o Socket.IO.

Uma técnica comum é o chamado [Long Pooling](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/23436/javascript/veja-como-o-long-polling-pode-te-ajudar-a-desenvolver-aplicacoes-em-tempo-real/). A ideia é que você abre uma requisição de HTTP no lado do cliente e espera por uma resposta. Se o servidor tiver um evento para mandar (no seu caso o tempo, de um em um segundo) ele mandaria uma resposta na hora. Caso contrário, ele espera até que o evento aconteça, com a conexão aberta (e o request HTTP pendente) e então termina o request. Isso requer que o cliente (no seu caso o navegador) fique em um loop fazendo requisições e lidando com as respostas.

No seu caso, eu diria que o mais fácil seria usar a API `event-stream` do HTTP. A maior parte dos navegadores hoje suporta essa API e você pode incluir um script na sua página para cuidar dos navegadores que não a suportarem. A ideia é a seguinte: toda vez que o servidor quiser mandar dados para o cliente, ele escreve `data:` seguido dos dados que quer mandar e duas quebras de linha (`\n\n`)k. Também é preciso mudar o `Content-Type` para `text/event-stream`. Seu servidor ficaria assim para suportar isso:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res, err) {
  if(err) throw err;

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    console.log('sending data ' + now);
    res.write(
      'data:' +
      now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds() + '\n\n'
    );
  }, 1000);
}).listen(3000);
```

No lado do cliente, você usa a API do navegador:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="current-time"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var currentTimeEl = document.getElementById('current-time');
var stream = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:3000');

stream.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});

stream.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  currentTimeEl.innerHTML = e.data;
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: esse metodo ficaria igual o codigo q eu mostrei, repeteindo as horas eu fiz com socket.io ;)

Comment: Ele ficaria igual se você acessar a página do seu servidor. Se você abrir essa página HTML você vai ter o efeito desejado. Da mesma forma, se você abrir um servidor de WebSockets (tipo o socket.io sem estar em modo de compatibilidade) e abrir uma conexão por `telnet` para ele, você vai ver o text se repetindo cada vez que chegarem mais dados. Assim é a rede.